Android getting error Hilt when running app
I am getting this error while running my android project, can someone please help.
I have the latest android studio jellyfish installed
and i am using hilt version 2.51.1
error: [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)

  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
1 error


this is my gradle app file,
I have added all the latest plugins still getting the error
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.isKotlinKaptPluginApplied

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

dependencies {

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.51.1")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03")
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes=true
}


What Kotlin version do you use? Also, does this answer your question? Hilt Unsupported metadata version in Kotlin

I faced this same issue. I solved this using these versions:
kotlin = "1.9.0"
hiltAndroid = "2.48"
hiltAndroidCompiler = "2.48"

Please make sure to change the hilt version in plugins of the project-level build gradle:
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false


It must have been a syntax error in your code that linter cannot detect. Try to check all the changes you have made in your code even imports

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I was facing the same issue. I figured out that I used different versions. I used com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.51.1 for the Gradle plugin and the old 2.44 version in the dependencies. Now are both the same and it works.
To simplify this process, you can either use variables and always upgrade dependencies by navigating to File -> Project Structure -> Suggestions to upgrade dependencies.
